# how to create WordPress responsive menu working like accordion for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created my WP responsive menu and it has several level sub menus, and I want to only show or slideToggle the particular sub-menu when tap or click on it.

I have put the span into the anchor tag to prevent redirecting to URL, so only click or tap on the span will slide the menu.

this is menu structure.

```
<nav id="nav" class="menu-menu-container" style="display: block;">
    <ul id="menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children menu-item-7"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/">Home<span class="arrow"> </span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-32"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/activate/">activate<span class="arrow"> </span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/register/">register</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-34"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/resetpass/">resetpass<span class="arrow"> </span></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/forgotpass/">forgotpass</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-38" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/activate/">activate</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-39"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/logout/">logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/member/">member</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/login/">login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**This is jquery.**

```
$('.menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a').append('<span class="arrow"> </span>');
$('.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a').append('<span class="arrow"> </span>');


$('.menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a > span.arrow').click(function(){
    var txt = $(this).text() == ' ' ? '  ' : ' ';
    $(this).text(txt);
    $('.menu > li > .sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
    if ($(this).text() == ' ') {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.menu > li > .sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
        },1000);
    } else {
    }
    return false;
});
```

for 2nd sub-menu.

```
$('.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a > span.arrow').click(function(){
    var txt = $(this).text() == ' ' ? '  ' : ' ';
    $(this).text(txt);
    $('.sub-menu > li > .sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
    if ($(this).text() == ' ') {
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.sub-menu > li > .sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
        },1000);
    } else {
    }
    return false;
});
```

So for 3rd and so on.....

```
$('.sub-menu .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a > span.arrow').click(function(){..
...
```

[image: example]

you can see what I have tried using this method I have to make this rules for every single selector.

so I don't want this, is there any way I can do this all by only just in single click handler, so I when only user click or tap on the particular sub-menu the only that menu will slide or toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few solutions.

- build 2 menus - mobile and desktop (mobile with nolink# for collapse events) this menus dysplays based on screen size
- Prevent default via JS, but u loss links functional
- But i recommend build your walker for this menu based on bootstrap. Here the walker
  https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php

(About walkers: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)